# How to use Ubuntu as client for my hikvision surveilance system?

Tags: client

I have a HIKVISION DS-7216HGHI-SH/A with analogue cameras connected to it.
In windows, Firefox requires a plugin (in .exe format) to display the videos. A plugin for linux on the website is rather dated (Ubuntu 10.04, 32-bit) and did not work. A quick search on the internet was not successful.

On android I use the iVMS-4500 application. I tried installing this on Ubuntu with the help of [ARChon](https://archon-runtime.github.io/), but it did not work. I also tried installing the same application on a VM running RemixOS (An android based distro) which did partly work. the application connects to the CCTV system, but shows the following:

[image: Picture of iVMS-4500 showing a transparent background]

I don't want to use an Android virtualization that is not local (gennymotion or similar). The system is not accessible from the internet.

A solution involving Windows Virtualization would not be acceptable. (Ideally I would like a solution that could run on a pi3)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running their Windows client software in WINE?

Comment: I did now (thanks for the tip),  but it did not work. I get initialization for ... failed, status e06d7363.

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.linux.com/learn/how-operate-your-spycams-zoneminder-linux-part-1

Comment: Well, I am aware of Zoneminder, but I am afraid it cannot be installed on the HIKVISION DS-7216HGHI-SH/A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install wine on Ubuntu
Then download [ivms 4200 Linux](https://upload.bkeesti.ee/Hikvision/Software/iVMS4200-Linux.tar.gz) .(https://upload.bkeesti.ee/Hikvision/Software/ )
Extract the downloaded file and double click  on ivms 4200 executable file.
Then you will get the ivms panel.

Download [Hikvision SADP tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Other-Internet-Related/SADP.shtml) and install .
Using the SADP tool you can reset  the device password of your Hikvision camera.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. What is the difference between the file you link to and the one provided here: https://www.hikvision.com/en/Support/Downloads/Client-Software ? I had no luck with installing the ivms 4200 via wine on my KUbuntu 18.04.

Comment: http://www.cctvforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=42569 No wine needed, though CPU consumption is horrible on 18.04.